# Having regular text within a lemma

Tags: math-mode, amsmath, theorems

I want the following lemma:

```
Given k\"ahler metric $g_{\al \overline{\be}}$ with associated Ricci curvature $ \text{Ric} =R_{\al \overline{\be}}$ the Ricci form defined by 
\begin{equation*} 
\p (X,Y) = \frac{1}{2} \text{Ric} (J X, Y)
\end{equation*}
we have the following local expression ...
```

The problem is that I like to have the statement of my lemmas to be in italics, but in this case the `\text{...}` command I use to write the Ricci curvature (ie `\text{Ric}`) puts Ric in italics and not plain text, I do not know how to rectify this?

By the way the command I use to set up my lemma is:

```
\newtheorem{lem}{Lemma}[section]
```

P.S. sorry for how badly formatted this question is but my LaTeX is quite poor.

Comment: Ric is a math operator and should not be typeset with `\text`, that command us solely for textual comments. Use `\operatorname` if it is a one of, or use `\DeclareMathOperator{\Ric} {Ric} ` if it is used often. This `\text` misuse is seen quite often

Comment: @daleif An answer, please.

Answer (score 8):

It is a very commonly seen error to use `\text` in this way. But `\text` is for textual comments *only*, it switches to the text font and the current font shape (as you mentioned).

Ric on the other hand is a mathematical operator and should be typeset, upright, in the current math font + have operator status.

For a one of you can use: `\operatorname{Ric}` , but it is often better to simply define a `\Ric`  operator via

```
\DeclareMathOperator\Ric{Ric}
```

And then use that. This also have the added bonus of a cleaner math code.

If Ric is not an operator, you can just use `\mathrm{Ric}` as a one off, or

```
\newcommand\Ric{\mathrm{Ric}}
```

for getting it as a macro (thanks to Willie for that comment)

Comment: It is much more common to use `\mathrm{Ric}` instead, FWIW. (Most geometers would not consider it an operator.)

Comment: @WillieWong added